# How to replace this function overload with a conditional type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function `callChild` that invokes a callback with some options.

If the `args` option is given, the callback is invoked with the specified `args`.

If the `args` option is not given, the callback is invoked with some default arguments.

I've accomplished this using an overload:

```js
function callChild<Args extends Record<string, unknown>>(
    // If `options.args` is given, call child with the return type of `options.args`
    options: { args: () => Args; },
    child: (args: Args) => void,
): void;
function callChild(
    // If `options.args` is not given, call child with argsDefault
    options: Record<string, never>,
    child: (args: ArgsDefault) => void,
): void;
function callChild<Args extends Record<string, unknown>>(
    options: Partial<{ args: () => Args }>,
    child: (args: Args | ArgsDefault) => void
) {
    const args = typeof options.args === `function`
        ? options.args()
        : argsDefault;
    child(args);
}

callChild(
    { args: () => ({ argCustom: true }) },
    (args) => console.log(args.argCustom), // Property 'argDefault' does not exist
);

callChild(
    {},
    (args) => console.log(args.argDefault), // Property 'argCustom' does not exist
);
```

My goal is to have correct typing of the callback's arguments in `callChild`.

However, overloads always seem to require a lot of repeated code. I'm wondering if I could accomplish the same result with conditional types instead of an overload?

I've made several unsuccessful attempts, such as:

```js
function callChild<
    Args extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Options extends Partial<{ args: () => Args; }>
>(
    options: Options,
    child: (args: `args` extends keyof Options ? Args : ArgsDefault) => void
) {
    const args = typeof options.args === `function`
        ? options.args()
        : argsDefault;
    child(args); // ERROR: Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type '"args" extends keyof Options ? Args : { argDefault: boolean; }'
}
```

Comment: How ironic it is then, that the simplest way would be to move the signature into an external overload: https://tsplay.dev/NrD73W

Comment: @vera. This loses the typing of custom args; all the custom args properties are `unknown`.

Comment: Oh right, I guess you would have to change the signature again then: https://tsplay.dev/N9bKVm